# How do I replace items in a file with items in a list

Tags: python, list, file

I have f1.txt, a file in which I want to replace all occurrences of 999 with the consecutive elements of the list lst. I have the following code, but it doesn't quite work.

```
lst = ['1', '2', '3'] 
f1 = open('f1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('f2.txt', 'w')
for no in lst:
  for line in f1:
    if 'some_text' in line:
      f2.write(line.replace('999', no))
      continue
    else:
      f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Sample from f1.txt:

```
tags text something
some_text blablabla 999
other text whatever
some_text blablabla 999
non interesting text
some_text blablabla 999
```

The result should be:

```
tags text something
some_text blablabla 1
other text whatever
some_text blablabla 2
non interesting text
some_text blablabla 3
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: You need to give a sample of the expected output. Do you want 999 to become 123? This is not clear from your question.

Comment: what is 'some_text'?

Comment: As written, this will create `f2.txt` with all lines containing both `some text` and `999` having `999` replaced with `3`.  What do you mean by "consecutive elements of the list lst"?

Comment: I added some more information in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = ['1', '2', '3'] 
f1 = open('f1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('f2.txt', 'w')
idx = 0
for line in f1:
    if ('some_text' in line) and ('999' in line):
      f2.write(line.replace('999', lst[idx]))
      idx += 1
    else:
      f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```